# setHomeButtonEnabled: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Whenever I build my Android app it generates the following error:

```
03-16 10:01:01.329    1312-1312/nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden, PID: 1312
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden/nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My MainActivity.java:

```
package nl.mikehagendoorn.efteltijden;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ListView listView1;
    private ProgressBar loadingDialog;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    TextView tvIsConnected;
    TextView txtTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Tab titles
        String[] tabs = {
                getResources().getString(R.string.attractions),
                getResources().getString(R.string.shows),
                getResources().getString(R.string.horeca),
                getResources().getString(R.string.stores),
                getResources().getString(R.string.information)
        };

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }


        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

However, when I build it for Android 5.0 it doesn't throw the error and it just works. 
Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

Edit -- I'm testing it in an emulator with SDK 16. The minSdkVersion is 14 and targetSdkVersion is 21

Comment: where are you testing it ?

Comment: What is the SDK of the testing device where it crashes? What is your min required SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an AppCompat theme like you have, your activity needs to extend from ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity (internally ActionBarActivity is an extension of FragmentActivity) and you'll need to use android.support.v7.app.ActionBar instead of android.app.ActionBar.

Also instead of getActionBar() use getSupportActionBar() as @Kim has already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator is probably running Android < 3.0, so if you want to use ActionBar there, use support library and
`actionBar = getActionBar();`should probably be `actionBar = getSupportActionBar`

Comment: *Edit -- I'm testing it in an emulator with SDK 16.*

Comment: The Android version of the emulator is 4.1.2

Comment: Which theme are you using for the MainActivity? Maybe that theme does not support ActionBar?

Comment: @Kim In my Manifest I've added this line: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: And what is the parent of your AppTheme?

Comment: @Kim Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: Again, if you're using the support library, use getSupportActionBar(). Otherwise use a non-compat theme like Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar.